# What does style "visibility:hidden" mean for the <html> element?

Tags: html, css

What does the style `visibility:hidden` do when applied to the `html` element? Does it have anything to do with the scrollbars, esp. in regards to IE7?

Background: Oracle Apex generates this code, and I'm trying to work out if it's causing an issue with an intermittently hidden horizontal scrollbar in IE7:

```
<style> html {visibility:hidden;} </style>
```

Comment: Interesting question. I'd keep the example code and explanation why you are asking this though. I can already imagine "it hides the element while it still uses up space" answers incoming...

Comment: I want to double-check that the problem I'm trying to solve has anything to do with this particular bit of code first. But I'll add the example code back in.

Comment: Try using IE8/9 with the IE developer tools. Set the browser/document mode as IE7. Inspect the DOM and hide the style to see if that corrects the problem. Or set a style `visibility: visible !important;` to override it. Granted this doesn't address how the style affects `html`.

Comment: On its own, it does the same as for any other element. So if the style does not get overridden for child elements, the whole page will be invisible. I don't know about browser hacks related to this, but is this a conditional stylesheet for IE?

Comment: I'm at work, which only recently upgraded to IE7, and I'm not sure I'll be allowed to install IE8 or 9. I managed to get away with a standalone install of Chrome (which makes debugging easy) but that won't help me with IE7. The lack of html/css debugging tools in IE7 is a huge pain.

Comment: There *is* a conditional stylesheet for IE7, but this particular line of code is added near the top of the HEAD tag, not in a separate css file; and it is unconditional.

Comment: Can you go into more detail on what you're actually seeing? Or post more code so we can test/view it? Can you add to the CSS to override that style to see if that fixes your issue? `overflow` typically deals with showing/hiding the scrollbars.

Comment: I've tried overriding the CSS (added `style="visibility:hidden;"` directly to the head tag. Chrome tells me this overrides the visibility attribute from the CSS style. It didn't make any difference to the scrollbar behaviour in IE7, however, so I'm now doubting this has anything to do with that. I'm still curious as to what the visibility attribute actually means when applied to the html tag, however. I'll probably ask another question about the horizontal scrollbar, with some sample code.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp: I don't know if you mistyped the above, but it seems that you should have tried adding `style="visibility: visible"` (not `hidden` as you state) to the `head` tag to see if it was affecting IE7 or not, since it is already set to `hidden` by your code.

Comment: yes @ScottS I mistyped in my comment - I was setting it to visible :)

Comment: The problem is something in the IR - the overflow is being chopped off at some level of the myriad DIVs, so IE is correctly not showing a horizontal scrollbar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Specifications

[According to the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#visibility), the `visibility` property should still affect layout. This implies to me that it should not affect scrolling if an element ends up causing scroll behavior. Also, any children set to `visible` should be visible within a `hidden` element.

---

### Observed Behavior

Using [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fMrn3/)...

**Firefox, IE 8-10, Opera**

Makes `visibility: hidden` on the `html` element not render the `body` (as it should) but still shows some rendering of the `html` itself as it shows the `background-color`. As BoltClock noted in his comment, this actually may be expected, since the `background` of the `html` is ([according to spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#special-backgrounds)) to become...

> "the background of the canvas and its background painting area extends
>   to cover the entire canvas."

These browsers also allow elements set back to `visible` inside to show as the spec for `visibility` indicated, so the `div` is showing and can scroll.

**Chrome and Safari**

It does not render the `background-color` on the `html`,  but it does allow the `div` to show and it shows the scroll bars. So Chrome is not propagating the `background` property to the canvas, presumably because its `visibility` was set to `hidden`.

**IE7**

The `background-color` for the `html` element does not render (like Chrome) but there are also *no scroll bars showing up* for the `div` element inside. This seems to indicate that it is not properly staying in the layout per the spec.

---

So it may be that the `visibility: hidden` property is *part* of your issue. Obviously, the background point relates not at all to your scroll issue, but does address the point of your overall question on how the property affects the `html` element.

In my opinion, the Chrome and Safari rendering would seem to be the most intuitive (what I might expect as a designer), as I would not expect the `background-color` to render (since the element is `hidden`), but at the same time, if I set a child as `visible`, then I would expect the browser to let me scroll on behalf of that child even if the `html` wrapper is set to `visibility: hidden`. *However*, whether the webkit browsers or the other browsers are closest to the spec is debatable, for as BoltClock noteed in his comment, the spec does not seem to indicate whether `visibility` on the `html` element should or should not affect the propagation of the `background` property).

Comment: Interesting. Hasn't solved my apex problem yet, but certainly sheds light on my question. Thanks

Comment: Opera (12.12 desktop) - same as IE 9